# Finding the longest word in a string in python

Tags: python

I have difficulty to find the longest word in Python

Here is my code

```py
s = "Mary is a little lamb"
words = s.split()

max_len = 0
max_word = "" 

for word in words:
    if max_len < len(word):
        max_len = len(word)
        max_word = word
        print("longest word: ", max_word, "(", max_len,")", sep ="")
```

But, The output shows two words, Mary(4) and Little(6).
Actually, when I removed 'Mary' in word, the output shows is(2) and Little(6)
How can I solve this?

Comment: Move the print statement outside of the loop, so it only prints after the processing is finished.  As you've written it, the print statement is inside the lop, so it prints on each loop iteration.

Comment: fyi, Python has a `max()` function which takes a key: `max(s.split(), key=len)`

Answer (score 1):

Move the print outside the for loop:

```
s = "Mary is a little lamb"
words = s.split()

max_len = 0
max_word = None

for word in words:
    if max_len < len(word):
        max_len = len(word)
        max_word = word

print("longest word: %s(%d)" % (max_word, max_len))
```

**Output**

```
longest word: little(6)
```